# Increase or decrease font-size by 1em when clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size

I am trying to make a font-size changer in jQuery.

The idea is that when you click an button with the label "a+", the font size of a specified element becomes bigger by 1em (so if the current font size is 2em it becomes 3em), and the label will turn into "a-".
When you click the same button with the label "a-", the font size of a specified element decreases by 1em (so if the current font size is 3em then it becomes 2em) and the label turns back to "a+".

I've only been able to increase/decrease the font size to a specified value, however, and would like some help making it increase/decrease by 1em.

Here is my current jQuery code:

```js
$("#ChangeFontSizeButton").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text()=='a+') {
    $("p").css("font-size", "1.875em");
    $(this).text('a-');
  } else {
    $("p").css("font-size","0.875em");
    $(this).text('a+');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
  
    <button type="button" id="ChangeFontSizeButton">a+</button>
    <p>Hello, this is a sentence.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

So, are you able to help me code this feature in a way that it increases (when the button's label is "a+") or decreases (when the button's label is "a-") a specified element's font-size by 1em?

Answer (score 2):

Using `$("p").css("font-size")` we can get the current font-size in pixels. Simply divide that number by 16 (After converting it to an integer), and you've now got the current size in em.

From there, just add one, and set the font size.

```js
$("#ChangeFontSizeButton").click(function() {
  var em = parseInt($("p").css("font-size")) / 16;
  if ($(this).text()=='a+') {
    $("p").css("font-size", em+1 + "em");
    $(this).text('a-');
  } else {
    $("p").css("font-size", em-1 + "em");
    $(this).text('a+');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
  
    <button type="button" id="ChangeFontSizeButton">a+</button>
    <p>Hello, this is a sentence.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to define all your text styles in em and use jQuery to change the base font-size on `body`. All the em and rem based styles will inherit from that